# How does my show page need to be written in order to display data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a newbie to the world of Ruby on Rails and I am developing a form that is dropdown in nature for the first time and you can see the code here in _form.html.erb:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@job, html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label "Poster:", class: 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.select(:status, options_for_select([['Nick Maloney','Nick Maloney'],
        ['Peter Brown','Peter Brown'],['Jen Morris','Jen Morris']])) %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label "Category:", class: 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.select(:status, options_for_select([['Landscaping','Landscaping'],
        ['Babysitting','Babysitting'],['Tree planting','Tree planting']])) %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label "Location:", class: 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.select(:status, options_for_select([['Dorchester','Dorchester'],
        ['Roxbury','Roxbury'],['Mattapan','Mattapan']])) %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label "Status:", class: 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.select(:status, options_for_select([['New','New'],
        ['Pending','Pending'],['Complete','Complete']])) %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= f.input :description, label: "Job Description" %>
  <%= f.submit 'Add Job', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
<% end %>
```

When I click on 'Add Job', it takes me to a blank screen which I have not been able to resolve on my own.

I have changed the code around a view times in the views/show.html.erb. I have had this:

```
<h1><%= @job.poster %></h1>
<p><%= @job.category %></p>
<p><%= @job.location %></p>
```

and this:

```
<tbody>
  <% @job.each do |job| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= job.poster %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

and I continue to get a blank screen or if I went to my jobs_controller.rb and developed it like this:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_job, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    # @job = Job.all
  end

  def show
    @job = Job.find_job(jobs_params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @job = Job.new
  end

  def create
    @job = Job.new(jobs_params)

    if @job.save
      redirect_to @job, notice: 'Your job was successfully added'
    else
      render "New"
    end
  end

  def edit

  end

  def update

  end

  def destroy

  end

  private

  def jobs_params
    params.require(:job).permit(:poster, :category, :location, :status, :description)
  end

  def find_job
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

I would get an undefined method for 'poster' for ActiveRecord object, but if I remove the code in the show action, I just get a blank page. I am out of solutions here and I have looked on SO, but nothing resembled a solution for me.

My routes.rb file looks like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :jobs
  root 'jobs#index'
end
```

I changed the show action to reflect this:

```
def show
    @job = Job.find(jobs_params[:id])
end
```

then I got a param is missing or the value is empty: job.

I did a rails console and I have this:

```
Job Load (1.1ms) SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" LIMIT ? [["LIMIT", 11]] => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Job id: 1, poster: nil, category: nil, location: nil, status: "New", description: "Your job is to plant trees all over the Dorchester...", created_at: "2017-08-01 10:29:40", updated_at: "2017-08-01 10:29:40">]>
```

I don't understand why I have nil on everything except description.

It seems that every form input like this:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label "Poster:", class: 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.select(:status, options_for_select([['Nick Maloney','Nick Maloney'],
        ['Peter Brown','Peter Brown'],['Jen Morris','Jen Morris']])) %>
    </div>
```

Gave me a nil in the rails console and only this one:

```
<%= f.input :description, label: "Job Description" %>
```

successfully inputted data, so something is wrong with the code for f.select, but I am not sure what.

Comment: You need to remove Job.find_job(..) from show action as it will try to override the current value of @job which has been set through before_action.

Comment: Also, find_job is not even a method In activerecord assuming you are trying to find the record based on id. It should be either find or find_by

Comment: @Ale replace this line `@job = Job.find_job(jobs_params[:id])` with this `@job = Job.find(jobs_params[:id])` . second this, why you iterate the loop of @job. it have only one job. If you want all jobs. than you can get it by this code `@jobs = Job.all` and you can iterate loop of `@jobs`

Comment: @Vishal actually OP can just remove the "find_job" line completely.  The before_action will get the record for him.  And `jobs_params` is not available at `show`.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn Sorry i didnt notice that method. yes you are right . no need to right anything in show method. but if he want all jobs than he need to write `@jobs = Job.all`

Comment: @Vishal, I changed the code to what you suggested, then I got a param is missing or the value is empty: job. I did a rails console and I have this:  Job Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "jobs".* FROM "jobs" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Job id: 1, poster: nil, category: nil, location: nil, status: "New", description: "Your job is to plant trees all over the Dorchester...", created_at: "2017-08-01 10:29:40", updated_at: "2017-08-01 10:29:40">]>. I don't understand why I have nil on everything except description.

Comment: @Ale spelling is correct of description ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to Replace your `_form.html.erb` with

```
<%= simple_form_for(@job, html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label "Poster:", class: 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.select(:poster, options_for_select([['Nick Maloney','Nick Maloney'],
        ['Peter Brown','Peter Brown'],['Jen Morris','Jen Morris']])) %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label "Category:", class: 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.select(:category, options_for_select([['Landscaping','Landscaping'],
        ['Babysitting','Babysitting'],['Tree planting','Tree planting']])) %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label "Location:", class: 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.select(:location, options_for_select([['Dorchester','Dorchester'],
        ['Roxbury','Roxbury'],['Mattapan','Mattapan']])) %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label "Status:", class: 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.select(:status, options_for_select([['New','New'],
        ['Pending','Pending'],['Complete','Complete']])) %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= f.input :description, label: "Job Description" %>
  <%= f.submit 'Add Job', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
<% end %>
```

In controller

```
   def show
   end
```

show.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @job.poster %></h1>
<p><%= @job.category %></p>
<p><%= @job.location %></p>
```

You got

> Job id: 1, poster: nil, category: nil, location: nil, status:
>   "New", description: "Your job is to plant trees all over the
>   Dorchester..."

because by mistek you have used `:status` in every `select` in `_form.html.erb`

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
  def show
    @job = Job.find_job(jobs_params[:id])
  end
```

to this

```
  def show
  end
```

The @job record is retrieved for you by the before_action

And use this in the show.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @job.poster %></h1>
<p><%= @job.category %></p>
<p><%= @job.location %></p>
```

Comment: Steve, I checked my rails console and I am going to continue to get a blank screen because of this: [#<Job id: 1, poster: nil, category: nil, location: nil, status: "New", description: "Your job is to plant trees all over the Dorchester...", I am not sure why I got a nil on everything.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from the show action in your JobsController :

```
@job = Job.find_job(jobs_params[:id])
```

Comment: Snake, I checked my rails console and I am going to continue to get a blank screen because of this: [#<Job id: 1, poster: nil, category: nil, location: nil, status: "New", description: "Your job is to plant trees all over the Dorchester...", I am not sure why I got a nil on everything.